# WCF Client, AllowCookies and clearing any current cookie?

Tags: wcf, cookies, forms-authentication

I have a WPF client that is using WCF to call into a service hosted in IIS. My WCF client has AllowCookies='true' so that the forms authentication cookie that IIS is using is passed back and forth with each WCF call automatically. This all works just fine.

But I need the ability to clear out any forms authentication cookie my WCF client is caching so that my next request is not authenticated. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>On wcf client, you would have access to</strike>

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request
```

Now this Request object contains cookies. You could loop over the cookie collection and remove the one you need.

> foreach(var cookie in request.Cookies) {   // }

An excellent article at [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190806/Send-Cookies-When-Making-WCF-Service-Calls) which explains cookie management on WCF client

**UPDATE**

HttpContext is only available at server side, so my previous answer was incorrect as pointed by Phil.

The correct way to do it would be rather clumsy as you have get hold of HttpRequest itself

```
MyWebServiceClient client = new MyWebServiceClient();


using ( new OperationContextScope( client.InnerChannel ) )
{
    HttpRequestMessageProperty request = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    //get the instance of your AuthCookie and make it blank
    request.Headers["AuthCookie"] = "";

    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[
        HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = request;

    client.InvokeSomeMethod();
}
```

Found this example [here](http://netpl.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/managing-cookies-in-wcf-client.html)

Comment: HttpContext is for server side support and not the client.